# MySQL - Foreign Key Constraint Error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, constraints

I've seen this problem loads of time on forums, but I can't seem to solve the issue for my particular situation.
I'm getting the following error on a simple insert.

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bag_track`.`job`, CONSTRAINT `fk_JOB_FLIGHT1` FOREIGN KEY (`FLIGHT_ID`) REFERENCES `FLIGHT` (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
```

Here are my table definitions:
Flight table

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BAG_TRACK`.`FLIGHT` (
 `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`FLIGHT_NUM` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL ,
`ORIGIN` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
`ARRIVAL_TIME` DATETIME NOT NULL ,
`STATUS` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
`CAROUSEL_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
`GATE_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
`AIRCRAFT_TYPE_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ,
INDEX `fk_FLIGHT_CAROUSEL1` (`CAROUSEL_ID` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_FLIGHT_GATE1` (`GATE_ID` ASC) ,
INDEX `fk_FLIGHT_AIRCRAFT_TYPE1` (`AIRCRAFT_TYPE_ID` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_FLIGHT_CAROUSEL1`
FOREIGN KEY (`CAROUSEL_ID` )
REFERENCES `BAG_TRACK`.`CAROUSEL` (`ID` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_FLIGHT_GATE1`
FOREIGN KEY (`GATE_ID` )
REFERENCES `BAG_TRACK`.`GATE` (`ID` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
CONSTRAINT `fk_FLIGHT_AIRCRAFT_TYPE1`
FOREIGN KEY (`AIRCRAFT_TYPE_ID` )
REFERENCES `BAG_TRACK`.`AIRCRAFT_TYPE` (`ID` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Job Table

```
    CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BAG_TRACK`.`JOB` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `STATUS` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `LONGITUDE` FLOAT NULL ,
  `LATITUDE` FLOAT NULL ,
  `SPEED` VARCHAR(45) NULL ,
  `JOB_DATE` DATE NULL ,
  `START_TIME` TIME NULL ,
  `TOTAL_TIME` DOUBLE NULL ,
  `COMPLETION_DATE` DATE NULL ,
  `USER_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `ROUTE_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
  `FLIGHT_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`, `FLIGHT_ID`) ,
  INDEX `fk_JOB_USER1` (`USER_ID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_JOB_ROUTE1` (`ROUTE_ID` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_JOB_FLIGHT1` (`FLIGHT_ID` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_JOB_USER1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID` )
    REFERENCES `BAG_TRACK`.`USER` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_JOB_ROUTE1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`ROUTE_ID` )
    REFERENCES `BAG_TRACK`.`ROUTE` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_JOB_FLIGHT1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`FLIGHT_ID` )
    REFERENCES `BAG_TRACK`.`FLIGHT` (`ID` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

I'm trying this simple insert

```
 insert into job (status, USER_ID, ROUTE_ID, FLIGHT_ID) VALUES ('UNLOADING', 1, 1, 2)
```

and getting the error above.
I have data in my flight table with the primary key of 1. 
I've examined everything on my DB for typos etc and I'm at a loss to see what the problem isI'd be very grateful is anyone can help.

Thanks

B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your tables must use innoDb engine as you can read from the [official doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

> Both tables must be InnoDB tables and they must not be TEMPORARY
>   tables.

For the Flight table you have `ENGINE = MyISAM` instead.

Comment: Well spotted. Thanks for your help Aurelio. Really appreciate it.